# Create database backup at specified path(BaseX)

Tags: xquery, basex

I want to take database backup at specified location, when i use db:create-backup() as this function only one parameter $db as xs:string, it creates backup at path "C:\Program Files (x86)\BaseX\data".

As i have to create backup at specified location, Can anyone suggest how can i achieve this.

Comment: I suppose https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Configuration#Database_Directory suggests you can use "GUI: Choose Options → Preferences and choose a new database path" and that directory is also used for backups.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your quick response, as my requirement is to take backup using xquery not from the GUI, where i will write scheduler to take backup at specified location.

Comment: Perhaps create the backup in the database directory using `db:create-backup()`, then move or copy that file, if you want to do that with XQuery then https://docs.basex.org/wiki/File_Module#file:move could help.

Comment: Thanks Martin, your suggestion in my mind as alternative, i was thinking to do it in a single step, if there is function having two parameter one parameter take db name and second parameter take path name where to create backup.